# Angular 2 passing an object using ngValue returns Cannot read property ... of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

When I use this in my template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{company.Name}}</option>
</select>
{{selectedCompany}}
```

Value of `{{selectedCompany}}` is `[object Object]`. However, when I try to get `Name` property of `selectedCompany` like this:

```
{{selectedCompany.Name}}
```

I get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:60:10 caused by: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

I am trying to figure out why am I getting that error. I think the property is there because `{{company.Name}}` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `selectedCompany` is not defined at the moment of template rendering. You have two solutions:

1. Use safe navigation operator (`?`) to "protect" your template until `selectedCompany` is populated with data:

   ```
   {{selectedCompany?.Name}}
   ```
2. Initialize `selectedCompany` variable in your component:

   ```
   selectedCompany = {};
   ```

Either of these will solve the problem.

Comment: That was it, that fixed it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @RavenLune You're very welcome! :) I see that you're new here, so please consider accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped you. (tick and arrow up button on the left side of my answer)

Comment: In the second case the Name is undefined

Comment: @RomanC `Name` is undefined, but `selectedCompany` isn't. If you read the error carefully, you'll see that is the problem in this case.